# Python flask server to retrieve certain records

Tags: python, flask

I have this following python code for a Flask server. I am trying to have this part of the code list all my vehicles that match the horsepower that I put in through my browser. I want it to return all the car names that match the horsepower, but what I have doesn't seem to be working? It returns nothing. I know the issue is somewhere in the "for" statement, but I don't know how to fix it.

This is my first time doing something like this and I've been trying multiple things for hours. I can't figure it out. Could you please help?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import os, json

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='flask')

@app.route('/HORSEPOWER')   
def horsepower():
    
    horsepower = request.args.get('horsepower')
   
    message = "<h3>HORSEPOWER "+str(horsepower)+"</h3>"

    path = os.getcwd() + "/data/vehicles.json"
    with open(path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        
    for record in data:

     horsepower=int(record["Horsepower"])

     if horsepower == record:
          car=record["Car"]
     
    return message
```

Comment: 1) Use render template for such a task 2) You dont append anything to `message`  - isnt it?

Comment: I don't know what a render template is. I just know my problem comes from somewhere in the for statement.

Answer (score 1):

The following example should meet your expectations.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import os, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/horsepower')
def horsepower():
    # The type of the URL parameters are automatically converted to integer.
    horsepower = request.args.get('horsepower', type=int)
    
    # Read the file which is located in the data folder relative to the 
    # application root directory.
    path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'data', 'vehicles.json')
    with open(path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    # A list of names of the data sets is created, 
    # the performance of which corresponds to the parameter passed.
    cars = [record['Car'] for record in data if horsepower == int(record["Horsepower"])]

    # The result is then output separated by commas.
    return f'''
        <h3>HORSEPOWER {horsepower}</h3>
        <p>{','.join(cars)}<p>
    '''
```

There are many different ways of writing the loop. I used a short variant in the example. In more detail, you can use these as well.

```
cars = []
for record in data:
    if horsepower == int(record['Horsepower']):
        cars.append(record['Car'])
```

As a tip:
Pay attention to when you overwrite the value of a variable by using the same name.